# JPQL @Query causing "unexpected token: ("

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have following method defined:

```
@Query("SELECT AVG(total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(t.name) total FROM DataTable t GROUP BY DATE(actiontime)) result")
Long countAvg();
```

However it causes this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected     token: ( near line 1, column 24 [SELECT AVG(total) FROM (SELECT     COUNT(t.name) total FROM backend.DataTable t GROUP BY     DATE(actiontime)) result]
```

But following SQL works fine:

```
SELECT AVG(total) FROM (SELECT COUNT(NAME) total FROM DATA_TABLE GROUP BY DATE(actiontime)) result
```

If i understand correctly, JPQL has problems with subquery. How should i create this kind of query then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think jpql supports `subselect` with `from` clause. As per [jpa docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_subqueries)

> Subqueries are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses in this release. Support for subqueries in the FROM clause will be considered in a later release of the specification.

You can use `nativeQuery = true` in the `@Query` annotation and run it as native query instead or rewrite the query if possible.

Comment: butNativeQuery does not support sorting